# How to make for loop in Android.mk file

Tags: makefile, android-ndk

I need to use for loop over files in Android.mk file.
I want to get something like that:

```
FILES_SO := $(wildcard $(LOCAL_PATH)/*.so)        
RES_SO_FILES := $(FILES_SO:$(LOCAL_PATH)/%=%) 
$(info 'So files' $(RES_SO_FILES))               

$(for MODULE in $(RES_SO_FILES),\         
    LOCAL_SRC_FILES += $(MODULE):obj/SHARED_LIBRARIES/$(MODULE)_intermediates/LINKED/$(MODULE)
)
```

Any ideas how to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function is [`foreach`](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Foreach-Function) and you only do the assignment once.

```
LOCAL_SRC_FILES += $(foreach MODULE,$(RES_SO_FILES),$(MODULE):obj/SHARED_LIBRARIES/$(MODULE)_intermediates/LINKED/$(MODULE))
```